# Amount of same strings in two arrays (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I am coding an text bot with Javascript. I have coded c# before, but this is my first Javascript program. So my question is, how do you get the amount of same strings between two arrays? So, let's say we have an array, which contains values "
how", "are" and "you". Another array has values "how","is","it" and "going". So, how can I create a function which returns 1 from those arrays?

Comment: What's the basis for coming up with the `1`? Number of same words?

Comment: It's the number of same values in the arrays

Comment: Thanks, I think I can do it from here on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
arr1.forEach(function (elem) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(elem) !== -1) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsg4h/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called array intersection. Calculate it, then take the length of the resulting array.

[Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is an adapted [underscore.intersect()](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection). Should work as long as all the native Array methods: `indexOf`, `every`, and `filter` are polyfilled

```
var intersect = function (array) {
    var rest = array.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return array.filter(function(item) {
        return rest.every(function(other) {
            return other.indexOf(item) >= 0;
        });
    });
}
```

Can be called like:

```
var dups = intersect([1,2,3],[1,2],[5,8,2]);//[2]
var numofdups = dups.length;
```